Example of functions $f$ and $g$ where $f\circ g(x) = x^2$ and $g \circ f(x) = x^3$ for range $(1, \infty)$
I'm just looking for examples of real functions $f$ and $g$ where $f \circ g(x) = x^2$ and $g \circ f(x) = x^3$ and the domains and codomains of $f$ and $g$ is $(1, \infty)$. No complex functions but those defined on real numbers only.
Can anybody help me?
I could only find either of the conditions as shown below:
i) Example solution for $f \circ g(x) = x^2$
take $f(x) = (x+1)^2$ and $g(x) = (x - 1)$
ii) Example solution for $g \circ f(x) = x^3$
take $f(x) = (x + 1)$ and $g(x) = (x - 1)^3$
The problem is I cannot seem to find functions $f(x)$ and $g(x)$ in one variable such that both these conditions are satisfied simultaneously. Any help is appreciated. Thank you.
Comment: The range (1, infinity) applies both to domain and codomain for both functions f and g. Inverse of the function does not necessarily need to exist. But if you find a function whose inverse exists, that's okay too. This question is not from any ongoing contest but from a 1997 contest. However that question asks to show no such functions exist if range condition not given which I am NOT asking cause I already solved that by myself. I am just asking for an "example" of such functions which is said to exist if range condition is given.

Welcome to MSE. Please use MathJax to type the math in your questions. Consider that many users of this site won't even read your questions if they are not properly formatted, let alone help you.

You've tagged this both [tag:contest-math] and [tag:recreational-mathematics]. What are you trying to convey with these tags? Are you using the latter tag because you've just set this problem for yourself for fun? Or are you using the former tag because this question was found in some contest? Please bear in mind that, when presenting contest questions on this site, we require you to state which contest it comes from, and the year, so we can verify that the contest is not currently open.

"for range $(1,\infty)$" is unclear: the range of which function? $f$, $g$, $f\circ g$ or $g\circ f$?

I have an explicit solution, but please, answer Theo Bendit comment. Where is this problem from? If it's from an ongoing contest you should be asking about it.

The range (1, infinity) applies both to domain and codomain for both functions f and g.
Inverse of the function does not necessarily need to exist. But if you find a function whose inverse exists, that's okay too.
This question is not from any ongoing contest but from a 1997 contest. However that question asks to show no such functions exist if range condition not given which I am NOT asking cause I already solved that by myself. I am just asking for an "example" of such functions which is said to exist if range condition is given.

@CoachJonathanRamachandran thanks for the precision. It is better to add the information in the question, as comments may be deleted or ignored by people.

Take
$$f(x)=2^{2^{\log_3(\log_2(x))}}$$
and
$$g(x)=2^{3^{\log_2(2\log_2(x))}}$$
